# STLport and Android NDK - STLport loaded as static, Linux/gcc ld reports "multiple definitions"

Tags: android, android-ndk, stlport

I've looked thru a lot of material on Android NDK and STLport.  I have complex app, java+native code, which loads STLport (a c++ standard library port).  The original codebase had "APP_STL := stlport_static" in the Application.mk in the project's "jni" subdir. Causes ld to load the lib static.  This caused many compile failures, in current SDK/NDK.

Tried to load as a dynamic lib, as per a suggestion. (In "../jni/Application.mk", set "APP_STL := stlport_shared")  With this, I get a clean compile, and load, and the app runs *flawlessly* on the Android armeabi-v7a emulator, *if* I disable checkJNI on the "dalvik" virtual machine.

But once I enable checkJNI, I get an "unsatisfiedLinkError" on the libapplication.so, which looks like it might result from STLport being dynamically loaded. So, I want to load STLport in static mode (logcat reports this after several other libs successfully loaded).  During the build, compile is ok, but I am getting two multiple definition errors, specifically: "multiple definition of 'vtable for std::bad_exception' " and of 'std::exception::~exception()'.  (I have also tried using "gnustl_static").

I am using gcc version 4.3.0 and make version 3.81, command line mode, and small wrapper around build-ndk, for android ndk-r9c, with a build target version of android-8, "ant" to build the .apk file, and so on.

Someone who has more familiarity with Android than me (I am a complete noob) might have seen this before.  If so, please advise.  Thanx. - Rus

Comment: What are the errors when you use stlport_static? I take it that it doesn't matter if you're using shared or static as long as it works?

Comment: I tried "APP_STL := stlport_shared", in Application.mk. Loads clean, but "Davlik" vm crashes with "unsatisfiedLinkError" on libapplication.so, the app, after loading some libs.  Original codebase used static libs.  I'm thinking maybe static libs use local pointers(?) so maybe static loading fixes the dalvik unsatisfiedLinkError?  (COde runs flawlessly on armeabi-v7a emulator, with "dalvik.vm.checkjni" property set to false.)  THere are lots of google-hits on searches about stlport's problems with multiple definition of std::exception(). Readng now. There is a solution here somewhere... ;)

Comment: Interesting... I'm using stlport_static no issues, just wondering what else are you doing that I'm not.

Comment: I have not tried this but I believe you can build it as a static library by including in your Android.mk file with `include external/stlport/Android.mk`. You may need to update your LOCAL_C_INCLUDES and add `libstlport` to your LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES. I would say give that a try. You may need to add some definitions to your source to get this working though.

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely possible to use **stlport_static** with NDK r9c. What object files are mentioned with *multiple definition* errors? Maybe, you are using some prebuilt libraries? Maybe, the gcc version 4.3 is problematic? Why don't you use the default (gcc 4.8)?

With that, the [NDK document](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk.git/+/android-sdk-4.4.2_r1/docs/text/CPLUSPLUS-SUPPORT.text) explicitly encourages use of shared STL, but you must not forget to call [System.loadLibrary()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#loadLibrary%28java.lang.String%29) in correct order:

```
System.loadLibrary("stlport_shared");
System.loadLibrary("Rusfuture");
```

Comment: Thx, Alex & Dannie.  I've got it working. Loading "stlport" as static solved the unsatisfiedLinkError issue for dalvik.  The multiple definitions involved exception-handling code in stlport, in a prgm "dll_main.cpp"  (I just commented out the following six lines in dll_main.cpp) #if defined (_STLP_NO_EXCEPTION_HEADER) || defined (_STLP_BROKEN_EXCEPTION_CLASS)
// --- MCL mod. generating "multiple defintions" failure at load time...  remove for now
// exception::exception() _STLP_NOTHROW {}
// exception::~exception() _STLP_NOTHROW {}

Comment: This is removed code: `code` #if defined (_STLP_NO_EXCEPTION_HEADER) || defined (_STLP_BROKEN_EXCEPTION_CLASS)
// --- MCL mod..  This is generating "multiple defintions" failure at load time...  remove for now
// exception::exception() _STLP_NOTHROW {}
// exception::~exception() _STLP_NOTHROW {}
// bad_exception::bad_exception() _STLP_NOTHROW {}
// bad_exception::~bad_exception() _STLP_NOTHROW {}
// const char* exception::what() const _STLP_NOTHROW { return "class exception"; }
// const char* bad_exception::what() const _STLP_NOTHROW { return "class bad_exception"; }
#endif `code`

Comment: Just to be clear.  This is a big result.  I can now use adb to drop the debug version of the .apk (built using r9c android ndk/sdk and "ant-debug" - using Fedora Linux in command line mode) on to an actual real device, running Android 4.1.1 (a cheapy "Digital2" tablet), and it runs and behaves well. The key was to set target build to "android-8", *and* load the STLport statically, so dalvik-vm loading can resolve the internal library references, I suspect.

Comment: Probably this `dll_main.cpp` is Windows specific?